# Symfony3 project deployment to prod server using Deployer.org

Tags: deployment, symfony, php-deployer

I'm trying to deploy my symfony3 project to production server Using `deployer.ord`. I've been through all around `deployer.org` and not sure what is going wrong. Below is my `deploy.php` file

```
<?php
/*
 * This file has been generated automatically.
 * Please change the configuration for correct use deploy.
 */

require 'recipe/symfony.php';

// Set configurations
set('repository', 'git@github.com:XXXXXX/YYYYYY');
set('shared_files', ['app/config/parameters.yml']);
set('shared_dirs', ['app/logs']);
set('writable_dirs', ['app/cache', 'app/logs']);

// Configure servers
server('production', 'dummysite.com', '21')
    ->user('2136439')
    ->password('123456')
    ->env('deploy_path', '/home/www/dummysite.com/web')
    ->stage('production');

/**
 * Restart php-fpm on success deploy.
 */
task('php-fpm:restart', function () {
    // Attention: The user must have rights for restart service
    // Attention: the command "sudo /bin/systemctl restart php-fpm.service" used only on CentOS system
    // /etc/sudoers: username ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl restart php-fpm.service
    run('sudo /bin/systemctl restart php-fpm.service');
})->desc('Restart PHP-FPM service');

after('success', 'php-fpm:restart');


/**
 * Attention: This command is only for for example. Please follow your own migrate strategy.
 * Attention: Commented by default.  
 * Migrate database before symlink new release.
 */

// before('deploy:symlink', 'database:migrate');
```

The error that i am getting is : `PHP Notice: Connection terminated by the server`

I have already tried this resource but still no luck
http://www.issart.com/blog/deployment-of-symfony2-application-using-deployer/

I wonder if i am using the right credentials (i am using ftp ones) for deployment.

I was also not able to find much of info online on deployer.org and a step-by-step on how to deploy and debug so any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

a bit later :)

```php
<?php
namespace Deployer;

require 'recipe/symfony3.php';
```

detail here : https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/blob/master/recipe/symfony3.php